# What does error order $O(t^2)$ mean?

Tags: error-analysis

What does it mean if something is $O(t^2)$? And more importantly, how would I check for this relationship? I thought it meant error proportional to $t^2$, and that this could be tested by plotting a graph of ln(error) vs ln(t), and it should be a straight line. Is that right?

I have read the wikipedia article. I don't know how to apply that information to my situation.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I had read that. I'm trying to apply the information to the specific situation I have, which is a second order integrator, which apparently has global error order t^2. Does that mean the error should be proportional to t^2?

Comment: For a numerical integrator the error would be on the order of some power of the integration step h. You have to be very careful with that, though. These estimates make certain regularity assumptions about the function that you are integrating, specifically that the Taylor series expansion exists and that it is convergent in every point on the interval. They don't make promises about the term O(h^2) being small. You have to explicitly check that in addition to performing the integration, which is only possible if you know something about the behavior of your functions.

Comment: *"I don't know how to apply that information to my situation."* -- In that case, you should maybe describe your situation.

Comment: You don't *check* - the algorithm will be $O(t^2)$ or not.  Big O is a complexity relationship.  In numerical method it would be an error dependency.   You don't have an ln(error) to plot - if know the actual answer then just use it.

Comment: I recommend you the book "First look at perturbation theory" it shows where they appear and their utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $t$ is the step size.

If $t$ is the integration step, you will make a certain error in calculating the integral. As you make the step $t$ smaller, the maximum error you make will reduce - and if the integrand is reasonably well behaved (in the sense that word was used when somebody calculated the scaling of the error) then you can expect that reducing the step by 2x reduces the expected error by 4x. This does not mean that the evaluation of the square root of error as a function of $t$ will follow a straight line; it does tell you that a slightly smaller step will on the whole give you a much better answer.

[Very good general explanation of big-O vs little-o on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364491)